# Proper way to connect 5v device out to 3.3v RPi input?

Tags: gpio

[image: IR Infrared Sensor Module]

What's the proper way to connect this IR Sensor Module to a GPIO input? I'm guessing it's output is 5v, not 3.3v that the GPIO wants.

Comment: I would use a level shifter, but first I would find out what the datasheet says. You may also be able to run it with 3.3v to VCC and not have a problem (though no guarantees).

Comment: I tried 3.3v VCC but the LEDs don't show any life. With 5v, one LED lights up and the other comes on when I wave my hand in front. I am able to drive a (5v) relay with the OUT line.

Comment: In that case I would go with a level shifter. You may have to do some searching if you are looking for one that can drive a relay or use a separate pin to control the relay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the device is sold as an Arduino module it probably does output at 5V.

A level shifter of some sort would be best to convert the 5V output to Pi safe 3V3.

I tend to use a couple of resistors as a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider).

A couple of resistors with one twice the value of the other would be almost perfect giving a voltage of 3.333V from 5V.  At a pinch you could use a pair of resistors with the same value as that would give 2.5V which will likely still be seen as high at the Pi.

Comment: Is there a resistor range that is more _comfortable_ for the components? like 1 and 2 Ω, kΩ or MΩ? I suspecting the values might affect current.

Comment: You shouldn't source or sink more than 16 mA to a GPIO, so very low values are not a great choice.  I tend to use resistors like 1k and 2K, but 10k and 20k should work as well.  I guess the highest values which work would be most comfortable for the components.  I'm a software type so treat what I say about electronics with caution.

Answer (score 3):

A level shifter is the safe option. They are not expensive. If you are just looking to drive a logic input a voltage divider should also work.

You state:-

> I am able to drive a (5v) relay with the OUT line.

I don't see anything on the board that looks like it would drive a relay (unless you are talking about a relay module with logic input). Directly connecting a relay risks damaging the device.

Comment: Yes, it is a relay module that I usually drive with the Pi's GPIO out output.